# How to make a stand alone Mac Terminal Program?

Tags: macos, terminal

I want to be able to save a file in a way that opening it with a regular double-click runs it. Also is there a mac equivalent of `@ECHO OFF` that makes it so no text shows up in terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the easiest thing to do would be to wrap your script or program in a tiny bit of AppleScript:

```
do shell script "/your/command/here"
```

Then save it as an application and it will behave like any other OSX application.

The shell shouldn't be printing the commands as they're run unless you're supplying the `-x` switch so I'm not sure what you want `@ECHO OFF` for.

Comment: So just put it all in quotes and save it as a .app?

Comment: @JShoe: Not quite. Use the "AppleScript Editor" application to write the AppleScript, then "Save As" and choose "Application". The editor should be be in `/Applications/Utilities`.

Comment: I don't have it. I'm running 10.5.8. Any other way?

Comment: @JShoe: That's where it is on 10.6.7. Ask Spotlight where it is, you should have it somewhere. It might be called "Script Editor" in older OSXs, look around in `/Applications/` and its subdirectories.

Comment: Not at all. Can I change the extension to .app?

Comment: What if you ask Spotlight about "Editor"?

Comment: Got it. So what's the format? Can't I just paste it all? Why "Do shell script"?

Comment: The AppleScript is just text, just replace the "/your/command/here" with the path to your command. "Do shell script" is just AppleScript's way of executing CLI commands, it is pretty much like `system()` in C, Ruby, Perl, etc.

Comment: So save the command in Bin, then do shell script "/usr/local/bin/filename.sh", save as program?

Comment: Sounds about right but mine says "Application" rather than "Program". And you'll probably want to `chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/filename.sh` to make sure it is executable.

Comment: I usually do chmod +x. Same thing?

Comment: Yes, +x is pretty much the same thing. I'm old so I use the raw octal permissions :)

Comment: Cheers. There's also `/usr/bin/osascript` for going the other way.

Comment: This works, but `do shell script` is needless rigamarole here.

Comment: rig·ma·role/ˈrig(ə)məˌrōl/ Noun.
1. A lengthy and complicated procedure.

Answer (score 2):

If you save a script with the file extension `.command`, it will be double-clickable in the Finder.

Comment: You'll still have to give it execute permissions and it'll still open a terminal window (at least my quick'n'dirty test case did), going through AppleScript doesn't open the terminal. Useful information nonetheless though.

Comment: Actually this works better because when dealing with infinite loops I would need to be able to quit it. But I would say that @mu , yours is still the best answer, this one just suits my particular needs better.